# mysql grouping over data where a sub grouping matches if clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I do have the following grouping query:

### **Query**

```
SELECT P.partner, COUNT(DISTINCT P.postid) AS nb_post,
COUNT(DISTINCT P.postvariationid) AS nb_postvariation,
COUNT(DISTINCT P.postvariationid) / COUNT(DISTINCT P.postid) AS avg_postvariation
FROM posts P
GROUP BY P.partner
ORDER BY P.id DESC;
```

**[Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7deed)**

The output matches the structure I'd like to get.

However where are some posts in the data which only have one variation per post. I'd only like to count post and variations where a post has multiple variations. I thought of a query like:

```
SELECT P.partner, COUNT(DISTINCT P.postid) AS nb_post,
COUNT(DISTINCT P.postvariationid) AS nb_postvariation,
COUNT(DISTINCT P.postvariationid) / COUNT(DISTINCT P.postid) AS avg_postvariation
FROM posts P
GROUP BY P.partner,P.postid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT P.postvariationid) / COUNT(DISTINCT P.postid) > 1
ORDER BY P.id DESC;
```

However this COUNTS only apply to the overall grouping and I'm not sure how to apply it the sub grouping. Also I get multiple rows for each post (which is obvious because I added a second grouping)

Thx I really appreciate your expertise and help!

Answer (score 0):

Below query should work for you

```
SELECT  P.partner
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT P.postid) AS nb_post
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT P.postvariationid) AS nb_postvariation
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT P.postvariationid) / COUNT(DISTINCT P.postid) AS avg_postvariation
FROM    posts P 
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  P.postid
                    ,COUNT(DISTINCT P.postvariationid) AS nb_postvariation
            FROM posts P
            GROUP BY P.postid
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT P.postvariationid) > 1
        ) Q
        ON P.postid = Q.postid
GROUP BY P.partner
ORDER BY P.id DESC;
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7deed/30)

EDIT: Try this optimized query which accessed the main table only once. 
However this query assumes that the values for `nb_postvariation` does not repeat across multiple values from `postid`

also for the better performance you may add a covering index on `posts(partner,postid,postvariationid)`

```
SELECT  P.partner
        ,SUM(nb_post) AS nb_post
        ,SUM(nb_postvariation) AS nb_postvariation
        ,SUM(nb_postvariation)/SUM(nb_post) AS nb_postvariation
FROM    (
        SELECT  P.partner,P.postid
                ,COUNT(DISTINCT P.postid) AS nb_post
                ,COUNT(DISTINCT P.postvariationid) AS nb_postvariation
        FROM    posts P  
        GROUP BY P.partner,P.postid 
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT P.postvariationid) > 1
       )P;
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7deed/32)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I knew about the join however is where a better solution thinking of performance? I have several gb data in an myisam db.

Comment: Yeah the performance will be a big concern for this query. Check if the new edited query works for you.